# Force flush count-type Observable.Buffer c#

Tags: c#, buffer, system.reactive

Building on this question which discusses flushing a time-based buffer:
[Force flush to Observable.Buffer c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944716/force-flush-to-observable-buffer-c-sharp), I'm having difficulty working out how to translate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944892) answer given there to the case where I'm buffering by count, not by time:

```
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();
var closing = Observable
    .Timer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 30))
    .Select(x => Unit.Default);

var query =
    mFluxObservable
        .Buffer(() => Observable
            .Amb(subject, closing)
            .Take(1));
```

I started using the same `Amb` logic, using an 'item counter' instead of Timer, but found myself going down the rabbit hole of trying to work out how to reset *that*.

Can you push me gently in the direction of working out how to implement my missing function?

```
var flusher = new Subject<Unit>();
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
var output = source.BufferExceptOnFlush(100, flusher);
```

My source is 'hot', if that helps...

*PS: I could figure something out using `Observable.Create` and some kind of internal counter, but not without locking...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it by using the source in the closing observable and merging that with a flushing observable. The following worked for me:

```
 var source = new Subject<Unit>();
 var flush = new Subject<Unit>();

 // close buffer every 3 values or when a flush value arrives
 var closing = source.Buffer(3) 
            .Select(x => Unit.Default)
            .Merge(flush);

 var query = source.Buffer(() => closing)
         .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

// some test values
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);

// flush buffer
flush.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that straight away. For fun I've posted my current best approximation...

Comment: Gngng, as usual with Rx, the solution is so simple, once someone else has worked it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with an `Observable.Create<T>` solution. In which case I think this extension should work

```
public static IObservable<IList<T>> BufferExceptOnFlush<T>(this IObservable<T> source,IObservable<Unit> flusher, int bufferSize)
{
 return Observable.Create<IList<T>>(observer =>
 {
     var shared = source.Publish();
     var closing = shared.Buffer(bufferSize).Select(x => Unit.Default);
     var query = shared.Buffer(() => flusher.Amb(closing).Take(1)).SubscribeSafe(observer);
     return new CompositeDisposable(query, shared.Connect());
 });
```

I have not tested it yet, but would enable usage like this

```
var query = myFluxObservable.BufferExceptOnFlush(myFlusher, 5);
```

It will work for both hot and cold observables as there is no double subscription

Comment: Just saw answer by Ned and that has licked it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got so far:

```
var flush = new Subject<Unit>();
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default).Publish().RefCount();
var closer = CloseGenerator(source, flush, 5);
source.Buffer(closer)

//...

private IObservable<Unit> CloseGenerator<T>(IObservable<T> source, 
                                             IObservable<Unit> flusher, int count)
{
     return Observable.CombineLatest(
                        source.Select((_, i) => i), 
                        flusher.Select((_, i) => i).StartWith(-1))
             .Select(ar => Tuple.Create(ar[0], ar[1]))
             .Scan(Tuple.Create(-1, -1), (prev, next) =>
                 {
                     if(next.Item2 != prev.Item2 || next.Item1 == prev.Item1 + count)
                         return next;
                     else
                         return prev;
                 }
             )
             .DistinctUntilChanged().Skip(1) //This is 'DistinctExceptFirst'
             .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
}
```